# XSL FO page break depending on line breaks of paragraph

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have to modify an xsl fo template and I'm really new on this and hope anyone can help me on this step.
One request is about orphan elements depending on lines of the paragraph.
There are list items like this

```
Topic Text
    1. List entry (first)
    ...
    x. List entry (penultimate)
    y. List entry (last)
```

The request is as followed:
If there is an page break between `x` and `y`, the last list entry has to be only on next page if the list entry has a minimum of 3 lines in pdf output. If `x` has less than 3 lines, `y` has to be on next page too.
like this:

```
widow = 2 if last list entry < 3 lines else widow = 1
```

Is this possible with xsl fo using Antenna House formatter?
Can you give me a hint where I can find further informations?
thanks in advance

Christian
EDIT:
I played around but I was not able to find a solution for counting the lines in last node. So I can't find a way to check the last node.

The code snippet:

```
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <fo:block background-color="{$color}">
            <xsl:if test="$myId != ''"><xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$myId"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
            <!-- full width for AnnexTemplate -->
            <xsl:if test="($parent = $AnnexTemplate)"><xsl:attribute name="start-indent">-<xsl:value-of select="$leftIndent"/>mm</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
            <xsl:call-template name="insertParaAttributes"><xsl:with-param name="stylename" select="$style"/></xsl:call-template>
            <!-- text before table -->
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::table"><xsl:attribute name="keep-with-next">10</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
            <xsl:call-template name="dummy"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:otherwise>
```

and the output attached. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1g3y.png)
Hope it helps for better unterstanding.

Comment: Please show a sample of the XSL-FO document you are referring to and perhaps excerpts from the PDF output. More help on this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent that I understand the description, options include:

- `orphans="3"` on the penultimate list entry (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#orphans).
- `keep-with-next.within-page="always"` on the penultimate list entry (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#keep-with-next).
- Integer value of `keep-with-next.within-page` on penultimate list entry and lower `keep-together.within-page` value on containing `fo:list-block`, though you'll have to experiment to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I will check them and give a reply.